# How to decrypt Chrome Cache files

Tags: file, google-chrome, caching, encryption

i need to decrypt some .js files from the cache folder in google chrome.
My problem is that this cache file are encrypted.
anybody here knows how to decrypt the files?

i know "Chrome Cache viewer" but i need to edit some .js files while chrome is running.

thanks and have a nice day

Comment: What makes you think the cache files are encrypted?

Comment: the files into the cache directory are .dat files. if i open the files, it looks like u open a .exe with notepad. it looks like the files are hex encrypted, but i tried to read the files with autoit and use _HexToString() to decrypt the files, but this dosent work. it just show "trash" like äöü...

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that an `.exe` file is encrypted, which is of course not correct either.